# Realm - Does the .currentUser() deliver the current logged in on the mobile device or ist there another meaning to it?

Tags: android, realm

I have checked the class `SyncUser` and the definition for the method `currentUser()` is: Returns the current user that is logged in and still valid.

What I want to know is, what exactly is delivered, when this method is executed? How reliable is the delivered value and what is the limitation regarding the definition of "current user".

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SyncUser.currentUser()` is just a convenience method for retrieving a single SyncUser that have logged in on that particular device using either  `SyncUser.login()` or `SyncUser.loginAsync()`. It only works if a single user is logged in, otherwise, you need to use `SyncUser.allUsers()`.

This is commonly needed when the app is restarted. You can then check if the `SyncUser` already exists and thus there is no need for them to log in again. This can be useful in the case when the device is offline and logging in is not possible.

The SyncUser is represented by what is called an access token, which has a default lifetime of 10 years, so valid in this context just means "Access token granted by the Server that has not expired yet".

Of course, that information cannot be fully validated on the client, e.g if the Server was restored from a backup losing information about a particular token, then the Client might think the token is valid while the server will reject it. In that case, you will receive a callback on the `SyncConfiguration.Builder.errorHandler(..)` with an event you can react to and log the user in again.

You can see an example of this in practice in this example here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/objectServerExample

Comment: The explanation I needed. I was trying to pass the SyncUser between the activities to make sure, the user has access. But this is not needed, since I can recover with SyncUser.currentUser(). Thanks!

Comment: So even if the user restarts the device, the access token will be valid and `SyncUser.currentUser()` will return the actual connected user? I simply want to understand how the mechanism is designed. Meaning, in which cases must the user actually relogin?

Comment: Yes the user you gets back is valid and connected. You are only forced to relogin if you manually called `user.logout()`. In many apps, you don't really want to logout once the user is logged in as that is just a needless step. Also, logging people out when they exit the app, mean they might not be able to use the app if offline, which is one of the key benefits of Realm.

Comment: Once again, thanks for the clarification. By using the objectServerExample I was able to establish the login/register. Now I will add some verfications to wrap it up. This is saving us a lot of time. Thanks!